# What is the SuiteScript 2.0 equivalent to nlapiRequestURL()?

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

Does anyone know the SuiteScript 2.0 equivalent?

```
nlapiRequestURL(url, postdata, headers, httpMethod)
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`http` and `https` modules are equivalent of `nlapiRequestURL()`

**HTTP SIMPLE EXAMPLE**

```
var response = http.get({
    url: 'http://www.google.com',
    headers: headers
});

var response = https.post({
    url: 'http://www.google.com',
    body: myPostDataObj,
    headers: headers
});
```

**HTTPS EXAMPLE**

```
 var response = https.get({
     url: url,
     headers: headers
 });
```